# Sonata admin type collection inline table responsive

Tags: responsive-design, inline, sonata-admin, sonata

I try to understand why sonata type collection is configure to be edit inline table, the table isn't responsive. On mobile screen when I've got a table with many field, all the field doesn't appear and there is no scroll to see them?
Someone have the same problem?

Comment: There is a horizontal scroll but the scrollbar is not visible. See [this](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/3365). Regarding non-responsiveness, try running `assets:install` command, maybe you're missing updated css files?

Comment: I have look your link but it's for the list action, I'm talking about the sonata_type_collection configure with edit inline, inline table. I found nothing about that!! I have also re-install my asset but nothing change!

Comment: Finally I use the CSS in the link about overflow-x:auto and i've got a scrollbar on any device. Thanks Irimiciuc :)

Comment: No problem, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [PR](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/3365) that wasn't merged yet, so there are changes that need to be done manually in the meantime:

Add this to a style.css in sonata's layout(extend the template and add the css in the styles block).

```
/* table list scrollbar */
 .box .box-body {
     overflow-x: auto;
     overflow-y: hidden;
 }

 .sonata-ba-list .pull-right.fix-overflow {
     position: absolute;
     right: 10px;
     bottom: 10px;
}
```

And in `base_list.html.twig` :

```
 <div class="pull-right fix-overflow">
```